# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException, and I dont know why

Tags: java, input, delimiter

I am working on a project for school, my code is giving me the error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
when I try to use a delimiter input statement twice.

I have tried it with only doing one input line and it works, but when I add the other line it gives me the error.

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

        input.useDelimiter("##");

        System.out.println("The delimiter is \'##\'");

        System.out.print("Enter the name of product 1, product 2, and product 3: ");
        String prod1 = input.next();
        String prod2 = input.next();
        String prod3 = input.next();

        System.out.print("Enter the quantity of product 1, product 2, and product 3: ");
        int quan1 = input.nextInt();
        int quan2 = input.nextInt();
        int quan3 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println(prod1+" "+prod2+" "+prod3);
        System.out.println(quan1+" "+quan2+" "+quan3);
```

The expected result is that if I enter 
fish##banana##ice cream###
and
3##4##5##
then it prints
fish banana ice cream
3 4 5

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown by an instance of the Scanner class to indicate that a retrieved token didn't match the pattern for the expected type or that the retrieved token is out of range

Answer (score 0):

Try following input:
`fish##banana##ice cream##3##4##5##`

I guess the new-line might be read as well, thus the first nextInt fails.
Perhaps you also want to use `input.nextLine()` and split the Strings at ##?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a custom delimiter? You can simply take input separated by new lines.

```
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Press enter key after every input");

    System.out.print("Enter the name of product 1, product 2, and product 3: ");
    String prod1 = input.nextLine();
    String prod2 = input.nextLine();
    String prod3 = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter the quantity of product 1, product 2, and product 3: ");
    int quan1 = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    int quan2 = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    int quan3 = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();

    System.out.println(prod1+" "+prod2+" "+prod3);
    System.out.println(quan1+" "+quan2+" "+quan3);
```